# Add menubar to VFB window - maya 2018

Tags: maya, mel

I'm editing "vrayVFBPanel.mel", to add "menubar" above it. how do you get "menubar" to appear in vrayVFBPanel?

[vrayVFBPanel.mel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDZY7.png)

When the script runs, 2 windows appear, and the menubar does not appear above it.

[maya window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gOQv.png)